# Intellisense in c++ builder?

Tags: intellisense, c++builder, code-completion, c++builder-2010

I'm very disappointed with c++ builder intellisense, so I'm wonder is there any good intellisense that can be used in c++ builder? Something like visual studio have "Visual assist". My current version of builder is 2010, is the x2 have better intellisense?

Comment: Why don't you just use Visual C++, with or without VA-X?  There's a free Express Edition of all Visual Studio languages with almost full editor functionality included.  For non-Windows development, Apple's Xcode is said to be very good.

Comment: I use lot of visual studio but some thing's are easy to solve in c++ builder, so for that reason I ask question...

Answer (score -4):

I doubt if there is a good C++ compiler...

Code Blocks allows the user to hide all the text within an opening brace and a closing brace.

DevC++ can only give colors to different stuff. And it's really old. I used to use it when I was learning C++ at school.

MS Visual C++ allows the user to hide all the text within a function or class and comments that are longer than one line. This is my personal favorite. But it's a bit heavy for old systems (like my 5 year-old laptop).

If I were you, I'd start testing any compiler I find for some time. This way you can see which one mostly suits you.

Comment: It's not because C++ is old that it is difficult to tool.  It is difficult to tool because it is a complex language with an absurdly complicated grammar.

Comment: I don't think that c++ is old language and that don't have good support for compiler. If you are ever use "Visual assist" with c++ you have to know that it have same intellisense as c#, even better...

Comment: Even if this answer had used the correct terminology (IDE or editor, instead of compiler), it still would be wrong.  C++ is very much alive and well.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me! Seems as if I have gotten some things wrong.